# How to show fullscreen popup window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Is there a way to make a popup window maximised as soon as it is opened? If not that, at least make it screen-sized? This:

```
window.open(src, 'newWin', 'fullscreen="yes"')
```

apparently only worked for old version of IE.

Comment: Upvoted because, it's a perfectly legitimate question. What "you" want doesn't matter one bit if it's a corporate web-app for an intranet.

Comment: Tell it to my lecturer - that's one of the requirements for my coursework :)

Comment: @Tanoku I agree with Rob, just because it sounds like a bad practice for a "web page", doesn't mean it is actually for a web site, have a think about the possibilities of internal applications utilising non-browsers, for exaample HTA, where a full screen window might be completely acceptable.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use `screen.availWidth` and `screen.availHeight` to calculate a suitable size for the height and width parameters in `window.open()`

Although this is likely to be close, it will not be maximised, nor accurate for everyone, especially if all the toolbars are shown.

Comment: can you explain it with example fiddle.

Comment: @DanishAdeel here: `window.open(src, "newWin", "width="+screen.availWidth+",height="+screen.availHeight)`

Answer (score 9):

What about this:

```
var popup = window.open(URL);
if (popup == null)
   alert('Please change your popup settings');
else  {
  popup.moveTo(0, 0);
  popup.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

What about this, I gave width and height value to a big number and it works

```
window.open("https://www.w3schools.com", "_blank","toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=4000,height=4000");
```

Comment: top=0,left=0 is closer to fullscreen.

Answer (score 8):

More than bad design - this "feature" is a recipe for UI disaster. There [were](http://hackademix.net/2007/08/07/java-evil-popups) a [number](http://beyondteck.blogspot.com/2007/12/fullscreen-in-firefox-on-mac-os-x.html) of [malicious](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/archive/index.php/t-11975.html) web sites which exploited the full screen view features in JavaScript to hijack browser windows and display a screen indistinguishable from the user's desktop. While there may still be a way to do this, please for the love of all things decent, do not implement this.

Comment: Don't worry about my website actually having this implemented - as I mentioned I've only done it to satisfy lecturer's requirements :) Thanks for the warning though!

Comment: If you're going to tell him what to do then do so -you're right (it's a bad idea)- but at least give a **real** answer also. I have asked some questions that have gotten answers like this and it is very annoying not to have an answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this. This works for me and with any link you want, or anything in the popup**

Anything you chose will be shown in a PopUp window in a full screen size within a PopUp Window.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function Full_W_P(url) {
 params  = 'width='+screen.width;
 params += ', height='+screen.height;
 params += ', top=0, left=0'
 params += ', fullscreen=yes';
 params += ', directories=no';
 params += ', location=no';
 params += ', menubar=no';
 params += ', resizable=no';
 params += ', scrollbars=no';
 params += ', status=no';
 params += ', toolbar=no';


 newwin=window.open(url,'FullWindowAll', params);
 if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
 return false;
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Open as Full Window PopUp" onclick="javascript:Full_W_P('http://www.YourLink.com');"></input>
```