# I want to open another chrome window in full screen mode when clicking on a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a html page open in a chromewindow.
The html page contains some hyperlinks. When user clicks on the hyperlink i want it to open in a new chrome window in full screen mode. please help how to achive it. I tried different JavaScript code and chrome extension but it is giving me error in console like.

Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.

Comment: [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172748/how-to-show-fullscreen-popup-window-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show fullscreen popup window in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172748/how-to-show-fullscreen-popup-window-in-javascript)

Comment: Well, you can't. The error message is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score -3):

You can do it like this in below code to force the browser to open a new window instead of new tab

```
window.open('page.php', '', 'width=1000');
```